# Using vector container hangs while using array computes quick for 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays

I came across an example from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-score-triangulation-of-polygon/), and looking at solutions I tried to implement it in C++ using vector as follows,

```
class Solution {
public:
  int minScoreTriangulation(std::vector<int>& A) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> memo(A.size(), std::vector<int>(A.size(), 0));
    return tri(A, 0, A.size() - 1, memo);
    }
    
  int tri(std::vector<int>& A, int i, int k, std::vector<std::vector<int>> memo) {
        if( k - i < 2) return 0;
        if( k - i == 2) return A[i] * A[i+1] * A[k];
        if( memo[i][k] != 0) return memo[i][k];
        int min = ((unsigned int) ~0) >> 1; // max positive number
        for(int j = i + 1; j < k; j++) {
          min = std::min(A[i] * A[j] * A[k] + tri(A, i, j, memo) + tri(A, j, k, memo), min);
        }
        memo[i][k] = min;
        return min;
    }
};
```

Running on small inputs the program works, but it hangs for bigger input,

```
int main() {
  std::vector<int> v0 = {35,73,90,27,71,80,21,33,33,13,48,12,68,70,80,36,66,3,70,58}; // hangs
  std::vector<int> v1 = {3,7,4,5}; // works fine
  Solution t = Solution();
  std::cout << t.minScoreTriangulation(v0) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

So I used two dimensional array, and it computed `v0` much faster.

```
class Solution {
public:
  int minScoreTriangulation(std::vector<int>& A) {
    int** memo = new int*[A.size()];
    for(int i=0; i<A.size(); i++) memo[i] = new int[A.size()]{0};
    
    return tri(A, 0, A.size() - 1, memo);
    }
    
  int tri(std::vector<int>& A, int i, int k, int** memo) {
        if( k - i < 2) return 0;
        if( k - i == 2) return A[i] * A[i+1] * A[k];
        if( memo[i][k] != 0) return memo[i][k];
        int min = ((unsigned int) ~0) >> 1; // max positive number
        for(int j = i + 1; j < k; j++) {
          min = std::min(A[i] * A[j] * A[k] + tri(A, i, j, memo) + tri(A, j, k, memo), min);
        }
        memo[i][k] = min;
        return min;
    }
};
```

Is it possible to make vector run in a reasonable time? Or is it dependent on other factors such as cache?

Comment: This code leaks memory. You call new to create an array, but there's no delete[]

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> memo` -- You are passing `memo` by value each time.  That should be passed by reference, i.e. `tri(std::vector<int>& A, int i, int k, std::vector<std::vector<int>>& memo)`.  Your second example, as pointed out, leaks memory.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ah that made it work. TY!

Comment: @E.vanPutten without `delete`, does the array stay in memory even after program exit or until exit?

Comment: @phoxd -- *does the array stay in memory even after program exit or until exit?* -- Don't write code this way.  What if that function is called in a program that must run 24 hours a day, seven days a week?  Would you want to get phone calls in the middle of the night saying that your program has eaten up all the memory?

Comment: Note: `int**` has nothing whatsoever to do with an array. It is a single-pointer that points to an allocated block containing pointers. It is a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `int`.

Comment: @phoxd, after your program exits the memory is released. But while it is running your program will balloon, become slower and slower and inevitably crash due to out-of-memory conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` by value instead of by reference:

```
int tri(std::vector<int>& A, int i, int k, 
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> memo) // <-- Passed by value
```

This will incur a copy each time `memo` is passed.

Maybe a very smart optimizing compiler could optimize the copy away, but you cannot rely on this.  Instead, make your intentions known:

```
int tri(std::vector<int>& A, int i, int k, 
        std::vector<std::vector<int>>& memo) // <-- Now passed by reference
```